# apache spark standalone cluster - spark-submit - ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to ubuntu:9000 failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When i am writing code in Intellij and spark 2.3.0 with master("local") and executing in Intellij giving me output. But, 
1)  if i start spark standalone cluster(single node)(./start-master.sh gives me spark master url and ./start-slaves.sh). and giving sparkSession.master("spark master url") facing issue like this :

```
18/06/03 20:48:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.43.2, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
```

2) and I created fat jar with "sbt assembly" command .then spark-submit throwing me error like below even i use --master local[7] (or) --master  spark://ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:7077.

Is there any issue with fat JAR Creation?

```
spark/bin>spark-submit --class apache.sparkSQL.sql_batch \
                       --msater spark://ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:6066 \                   
                       --deploy-mode cluster
                       /home/user/level_2/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/batch-sparkSQL.jar 10

    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to ubuntu:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

I struck here .please help to reduce this. thanks in advance

my code is below:

```
    package apache.sparkSQL

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object sql_batch //extends App
{

  case class Employee(id:Int,name:String,mobile:String)

  case class Car(id:Int,brand:String,model:String)

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit ={

    println("hello ! World")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark SQL Demo").master("spark://ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:7077").getOrCreate()
    var myrdd1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/home/user/IdeaProjects/stream_trend/src/main/resources/batch_data/records.txt")
    var myrdd2 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/home/user/IdeaProjects/stream_trend/src/main/resources/batch_data/another.txt")


    //myrdd.foreach(println)

    import spark.implicits._

    //case class Employee(id:Int,name:String,mobile:String)
    val df1 = myrdd1.map(_.split(",")).map(attri => Employee(attri(0).toInt, attri(1), attri(2))).toDF()
    val df2 = myrdd2.map(_.split(",")).map(attri => Car(attri(0).toInt,attri(1),attri(2))).toDF()

    df1.show()
    df2.show()

    val jn_df = df1.join(df2,df1.col("id")===df2.col("id"),"right")

    jn_df.select(df2("id"),$"name",$"brand").show()
   }

}
```

build.sbt file is :

```
    name := "stream_trend"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
mainClass in assembly := Some("apache.sparkSQL.sql_batch")
resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
assemblyJarName in assembly := "batch-sparkSQL.jar"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"

)
```

input data files are 3 column data like below :
11,Maruti,swift

22,BMW,benz

Comment: Open `/etc/hosts` on all machines of your Spark cluster and remove all lines with `127.0.1.1`

Comment: I was only referring to `ConnectException`, not that one. I don't know SBT, but I can tell you that `spark-core`, for example, should not be part of the fat JAR because it's already on the Spark CLASSPATH

Comment: Personally, I would start with `spark-shell --master spark://ubuntu.ubuntu-domain:7077`, and see what happens

Comment: if i remove 127.0.1.1 line from host file , i can't start standalone cluster. ./start-master.sh throws unknownhost exception

Comment: Okay, fine. That's just a networking problem. Nothing about that is going to fix a class cast exception. Does spark shell work?

Comment: in spark-shell --master <url> , when doing rdd.toDF() , facing same issue .i.e. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to ubuntu:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;